# taskeng.exe keeps popping up - java program

Tags: java, windows, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have scheduled a java process to run (every 5 mins) under windows task scheduler as

```
java -jar c:\java\ABC.jar
```

I expect this task to run silently in background once every 5 minutes and print result only if certain conditions are met. Instead what it is doing is giving a popup window (taskeng.exe) every 5 minutes which will go away automatically unless there is a result to print. Although window is there for 3-4 seconds, it disturbs me every 5 minutes. What can i change to make sure i see the window only when there is a result to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With windows 7 and upper is possible to do this by setting the task to user SYSTEM or marking to execute whether user is loggedon or not

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnTQA.png]